# Titles on both top and bottom of MATLAB image

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am plotting a row of figures (images, not plots) using MATLAB subplot. I would like one title on the top of each image, and another one at the bottom. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a combination of `title` and `text` annotations. Basically getting the position of the title, and then shifting it below the image, centered. The nice thing is that the title is automatically placed at the top of the axes so you only need to get its position and apply a shift to place the text.

```
A = imread('pears.png');
B = imread('peppers.png');


figure;

subplot(1,2,1)

h1 = imshow(A);

[HeightA,~,~] = size(A);

hT1 = title('Pears at the top');

T1Pos = round(get(hT1,'Position')); %// Get the position

hT1_2 = text(T1Pos(1),T1Pos(2) + HeightA+50,'Pears at the bottom','HorizontalAlignment','center'); %// Place the text


subplot(1,2,2)
h2 = imshow(B);

[HeightB,~,~] = size(B);

hT2 = title('Peppers at the top');

T2Pos = round(get(hT2,'Position'));

hT2_2 = text(T2Pos(1),T2Pos(2) + HeightB+50,'Peppers at the bottom','HorizontalAlignment','center');
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

I use a shift of 50 pixels but you can play with it of course. For the title on the top you could also use text annotations, but it's a bit simpler using the title function in my opinion since it goes at the top by itself.

Lastly, if you want to place text at the bottom to create a legend, you might want to set the property `'HorizontalAlignment'` back to its default 'left'.

Is this what you had in mind?